# Creating Dev and Prod deployments using CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

New to AWS CDK, so please bear with me. I am trying to create multi-deployment CDK, wherein the Dev should be deployed to Account A and prod to Acocunt B.

I have created 2 stacks with the respective account numbers and so on.

```
mktd_dev_stack = Mktv2Stack(app, "Mktv2Stack-dev",

env=cdk.Environment(account='#####', region='us-east-1'),
stack_name = "myStack-Dev",

# For more information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/environments.html
)
```

the Prod is similar with the Prod account and different name. When I run them I plan on doing

`cdk deploy Mktv2Stack-dev`

and simiar for prod.

I am using the cdk 2.xx on Python

What my question is, does this setup give me an ability to pass a parameter, say details which is a dict object of names and criteria for resources that will be set up ? Or is there a way for me to pass parameter/dict from app.py to my program_name.py so that I can look up values from the dict and set them to resources accordingly.

Regards Tanmay

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**  Use a single stack and pass in the stg/prod as an env var to `app.py`.

Pass config down from `app.py` > Stacks > Constructs as Python Parameters (constructor args).  Avoid using CDK Parameters<sup>*</sup> for config, says [AWS's CDK Application Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps).

Practically speaking, you pass the account or alias as a environment variable, which `app.py` reads to perform the metadata lookups and set the stack props. Here's a node-flavoured version of this pattern:

```sh
AWS_ACCOUNT=123456789012 npx cdk deploy '*' -a 'node ./bin/app' --profile test-account"
```

##### Why not 2 stacks in `app.py`, one for PROD and one for STAGING?

A 2-stack approach can certainly work. The downsides are that you rarely want to deploy both environments at the same time (outside a CI/CD context).  And cross-account permissions are trickier to handle safely if mixed in a single `cdk deploy`.

##### Customising Constructs for different environments

Within your code, use a dict, class or whatever to return the configuration you want based on an account or region input. Finally, pass the variables to the constructs.  Here's an example of code that uses `account`, `region` and `isProduction` props to customise a s3 bucket:

```js
const queriesBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'QueriesBucket', {
  bucketName: `${props.appName.toLowerCase()}-queries-${props.env.account}-${
    props.env.region
  }`,
  removalPolicy: props.isProduction
    ? cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN
    : cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
  versioned: props.isProduction,
  lifecycleRules: [
    {
      id: 'metadata-rule',
      prefix: 'metadata',
      noncurrentVersionExpiration: props.isProduction
        ? cdk.Duration.days(30)
        : cdk.Duration.days(14),
    },
  ],
});
```

---

* "Parameter" has different meaning in Python and CDK.  Passing variables between constructs in code using *Python Parameters* (=method arguments) is a best practice.  In CDK-speak a [Parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/parameters.html) has the special meaning of a variable value passed to CloudFormation at deploy time.   These are not CDK best practice.

Comment: Hey, I ended up using multiple stacks and was able to pass the params from app.py to the stack_main_fn.py, here I passed the deployment params for stg and prod from the stacks themselves.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.  For completeness, I edited my answer to emphasise the one-vs-two stack choice.  I originally thought your question was whether to use CDK parameters or not.